# Core Data background saving doesn't work

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I changed my data (pressed onBackgroundChange) and saved it. I didn't got any error. In my log I see a "*_* change successfully" status.

```
-(IBAction) onBackgroundChange:(id)sender
{
 AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
 context.parentContext = app.managedObjectContext;
 [context performBlock:^
 {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Thread"];

    NSArray *array = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    if (array.count > 0)
    {
        Thread *thread = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        thread.threadInfo = @"background thread";
        NSLog(@"___ change successfully");
    }
    if (![context save:nil])
    {
        NSLog(@"thread save error");
    }
 }];
}
```

Then I stopped a program and ran again. My onDescription log is

```
__ thread: main thread.
```

What is wrong?

```
-(IBAction) onDescription:(id)sender
{
 AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Thread"];

 NSArray *array = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

 if (array.count > 0)
 {
    Thread *thread = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"__ thread: %@", thread.threadInfo);
 }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that calling `save` on `context` will call it on it's `parentContext` too?

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier, you are right. I need to add [app.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            [app.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        }];

Comment: cool. you may want to vote up on my comment or something;)